# "alt+É" shortcut in excel 2013

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a french version of excel 2013 which uses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>É</kbd> keyboard shortcut to access the "Data" tab ("DONNÉES" tab in french; see picture below):

[image]

I have a french keyboard (azerty keyboard) and did not find any way how to access to this shortcut. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

1. type 'Alt' to access to menu
2. type 'Alt'+'é' to access to the "Data" tab